# Array.apply(null, Array(9)) vs new Array(9)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of zeroes and I can get the desired result by using:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(9)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0)
```

but I get the wrong thing if I use:

```
new Array(9).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0)
```

And for that matter any attempt to map on the result of `new Array(len)` fails to return the expected array on a mapping. Can someone help me understand why this is the case?